# native-base drawer tap to close not taking into account openDrawerOffset

Tags: react-native, drawer, native-base

I'm using a Native-Base `Drawer` component, and I'm setting the `openDrawerOffset` value myself to be 300 wide (see code below). My main problem is `tapToClose` is acting as if the drawer is the default width and only responding to a tap within the last 15% of the screen or so.

Is this a bug in native-base? And is there a workaround?

My code is below:

```
<Drawer
    tapToClose={true}
    openDrawerOffset={1 - (300 / Dimensions.get('window').width)} // this has to be 300 wide
    initializeOpen={true}
    ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }} // not really using this anymore
    content={
        <SideBarView navigator={this.navigator} closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer.bind(this)} />
    }
    onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >
    <MainViewTitlebar 
        title={this.props.title}
        openDrawer={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}
        navigation={this.props.navigation}>
    </MainViewTitlebar>
    <View style={styles.content}>
        {this.renderMainView()}
    </View>
</Drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the **panCloseMask** prop same as **openDrawerOffset** to achieve that.